# Getting an Error When adding Ads

Tags: android, ads

So I'm trying to add ads into my program and as you can see this is the xml

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
    app:adSize="BANNER" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

I get the error

```
Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

I searched through stackoverflow and on google for a solution and they always told me to put

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

However I already have it so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you have to use the adview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can go through the official adview tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals).